# .removeAll() no longer working on devices running iOS 16+

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I have the removeAll function in my app. It works on iOS 15.7, but not on iOS 16+.

I've looked at the official developer documentation, and it doesn't mention any changes that could've happened in iOS 16+.

Further searching hasn't brought up any mention of this.

What has changed in iOS16+, that has caused this?

UPDATED QUESTION BELOW:

This method is called when user submits an answer to a question. The user's answer is stored as a string literal variable. The user's answer must be cleared from the screen whether the answer is correct or wrong.

I used another part of the app in iOS16+, which uses removeAll to empty an array. It emptied the array. I now suspect that removeAll should only be used on arrays. The user's answer in the code listing below should be assigned empty double quotes, instead of calling the removeAll method.

```
func checkAnswer() {
        cancelDisabled = true
        switchLanguageDisabled = true
        attemptFinished = true
        answered = true

        if replaceApostrophesWithBackSlashes(userAnswer: userAnswer.allowedCharacters(string: userAnswer.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).lowercased())) == foreignNativeAnswer.allowedCharacters(string: foreignNativeAnswer.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).lowercased()) {

            aurotorial.speak(native: dataOps.removeEverythingInBrackets(nativeWord: nativeWordWithoutBrackets), foreign: dataOps.removeDashes(foreignWord: foreignWordWithoutDashes), language: (testSectionThings?[questionCounter].languageSection?.language)!, changeVoiceSpeed: changeVoiceSpeed ?? 0.25, maxLoops: numberSpeechLoops ?? 1)

            updateWordCounters(correct: true)
            userAnswer.removeAll()
            languageColour = .green
            showTapSkip = false
            showNextTimeDisabled = true

            let englishAnswerFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
            let promptAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: englishAnswerFont,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.7, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            ]

            languageText = NSAttributedString(string: foreignNativeAnswer, attributes: promptAttributes)

            nativeForeignPlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Correct answer, well done!", comment: "Correct answer"))

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + dataOps.determineTextToSpeechDelay(changeVoiceSpeed: changeVoiceSpeed ?? 0.25, numberForeignCharacters: foreignWordWithoutDashes.count)) {
                self.prepareForNextQuestion()
            }
        } else {
            updateWordCounters(correct: false)
            yourAnswerPrompt = "Your answer: "
            wrongAnswer = "\(userAnswer)"
            userAnswer.removeAll()
            foreignNativeAnswer.removeAll()
            languageColour = .blue
            showTapSkip = false
            iKnowThisDisabled = false

            let wrongAnswerFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
            let wrongAnswerAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: wrongAnswerFont,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.7, alpha: 1)
            ]

            languageText = NSAttributedString(string: foreignNativeAnswer, attributes: wrongAnswerAttributes)

            answerDisabled = true

            let separator = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: noTestSectionThingsAttributes)
            let tapAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Tap a blue button, then ", comment: "Answer field tap skip 1"), attributes: noTestSectionThingsAttributes)
            let skipImageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
            skipImageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "skip.png")?.withTintColor(.systemBlue)
            let skipImageAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: skipImageAttachment)
            let nextQuestionAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString(".", comment: "Answer field tap skip 2"), attributes: noTestSectionThingsAttributes)
            let NSMutableAttributedStringArray = [tapAttributedString, skipImageAttributedString, nextQuestionAttributedString]
            nativeForeignPlaceholder = NSMutableAttributedStringArray.join(withSeparator: separator)
        }
        enableHint()
        enableSkip()
    }
```

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: The problem almost definitely isn't where you think it is. Please include some code that demonstrates the actual problem you are describing.

Comment: @jrturton I've edited my question, with code example below where it says:  "updated question below:".

Comment: `removeAll()` on a String is working as expected. Your issue is somewhere else. Instead of calling `removeAll()` you simply could assign an empty String.

Comment: @Carsten Assigning empty string works on iOS 15.7, but again, doesn't work on iOS 16+.

Comment: @Tirna then your issue is somewhere else. Did you verify that `.removeAll()` is behaving the same in a playground or another project?